# web2py : select clause to get first x number of records

Tags: postgresql, web2py

Using PostGres, is there a way to get only the first 10 records in a query or should I be writing a raw SQL in that case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the "limitby" parameter, check this, it takes to parameters the start and the end. In the following example it starts to fetch from index to index 2 (not including the end) so it fetches the first and second rows in the query

```
enter code here

>>> for row in db().select(db.person.ALL, limitby=(0, 2)):
    print row.name
Alex
Bob
```

Check this http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#select